# PHP parsing via str_replace, ereg_replace - how to exclude a section of the target text?

Tags: php, parsing, formatting

I have an old custom built content management system in PHP, where users can write articles.

When the body text is displayed, I do a bunch of str_replace and ereg_replace calls to parse links and headings and other bits.

Now, there is a need to be able to enter a block of HTML code within the body text (occasionally) and have it not-parsed by the before-mentioned functions. These blocks should actually be rendered as HTML.

The block could be surrounded in a tag (i.e. [html] etc) to identify it but how do I exclude parsing of this section when I'm basically just running the before-mentioned functions over the entire body text block?

Comment: Split up your complete text block into an array, separating the bbcode-parts from the html block. Then apply your manual str_replace calls only on each second array block. Afterwards merge again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you need to parse something that does *not* include the area you want to leave as-is. So here's one way you might do that:

For each `[html]` block, generate a unique identifier (e.g. through `uniqid` or hashing something, possibly the contents of the block). Check that this identifier (which should be something that does *not* get affected by your other parsing, so alphanum would be a good choice) does not actually exist in the text. If it does, generate another.

Save the identifier and the contents of the corresponding `[html]` block in an array using the identifier as a key. Then replace the substring `[html]blah[/html]` with `[html]identifier[/html]` in your input.

Proceed with parsing as normal, and when you are done replace back the `[html]identifier[/html]` bits with the real content. You can do this with just one call to `preg_replace` for all blocks if you take advantage of the `/e` (evaluate replacement string as code) option.

Comment: http://dev.xoofoo.org/dev_xoops_20181/d7/ded/a01009.html here's a code example of how the above approach can be done.